# Why is n reducing?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to write a simple Factory function that returns a function, that accepts a callback.

This callback `function (func, n)` takes 2 params, first a function, second a number.
All it does is call `func` incrementing `n` each time.
`func` is a function expression `shell`, that calls the callback and return the result `n`.

In the `console.log`, `b4` means before the callback is called, and `after` mean after.

What I'm confused about is, why is the output of `after` reducing?

```js
var factory = function (cb) {

  var shell = function (n) {
    console.log('b4: ' + n);
    var rs = 0;
    if (n && n < 5) {
      rs = cb(shell, n);
      console.log('after: ' + n + ' // huh?');
      console.log('return rs: ' + rs);
      return rs;
    }
    console.log('return n: ' + n);
    return n;
  };
  return shell;
}

var a = factory(function (func, n) {
  return func(n + 1);
});
console.log('a: ' + a(1));
```

Jsbin: https://jsbin.com/raqiwom/edit?js,console

Comment: because of recursion, you recursively call shell, but `n` in each iteration remains unchanged by the call

Comment: The recursive call that prints *b4* is before the one that prints *after*, so you see *b4* counting up, then *after* counting down as each recursive call returns.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a recursion structure. The "rs = cb(shell, n);" is executed before "console.log('after: ' + n + ' // huh?');", and it invokes the "shell" function.